# Using hibernate 5.0.2 with glassfish4.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm dealing with the configuration of my persistence.xml. I think that I wrote the properties right, but there has to be a reason, why my tables are not created in MYSQL.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
   version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__MyProject</jta-data-source>


        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />


            <!-- needed when 'transaction-type="JTA"' -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
            value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I also tried update, validate and create. When I use:

```
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

the tables are created, but I really want to know, if I just forgot to install something concerning glassfish or hibernate.

Here is a ahortcut from my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> -->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version> 
    </dependency>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: im sorry, i dont understand the question? you said you cant create the ddl automatically but after adding `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>` it works?

Comment: Which would indicate the standard EclipseLink of Glassfish is used rather than Hibernate. Which would make sense since Hibernate is not configured as the persistence provider.

Comment: I'm sorry. That wasn't very good explained. According to a Book, I'm working with, I should work with hibernate. But in that book, they are using the wildfly server, so I think, Gimby is right, and I should stick with eckipselink, as I'm using glassfish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glassfish by default is bundled with EclipseLink as the persistence provider. As such if you must use a different provider, you will have to manually configure it.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.1">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> <!-- this -->
 ...
</persistence>
```

If you have no specific reason to be using Hibernate other than "that is what I have used in the past", consider just sticking with what is bundled with the container. Glassfish is tested to work with EclipseLink, if you force Hibernate into the technology stack and you run into compatibility problems, you'll have a harder time getting help with it.

If anything, it makes your application lighter as well since you don't need to deploy a pile of Hibernate classes with your application.

Comment: in version 5, `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` is deprecated (see README file in hibernate-entitymanager lib (wich is depracated too !). Now, it's `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`.

Comment: @slim it has been changed